# finding number of rows affected or retrieve

Tags: php, mysql

i am have problems with retrieving the number of rows affected or retrieved from the database. when I check the value of $myslqi->affected_rows it has very unexpected values.

```
      echo $_GET['User_Id'];
   $ClientIP=get_client_ip_server();
   $query= "select IP from iptable where IP=?";
   $stmt=$mysqli->stmt_init();
   $stmt->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $IP);
   $IP=$ClientIP; // Must be retrieved dynamically
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->bind_result($ip);
   $stmt->fetch();
   echo $stmt->affected_rows;
```

in this code the affected rows says `-1` however there is value in database.. how to check the number of rows in my case

Comment: When doing a SELECT you have to use `$stmt->num_rows;`

Comment: $stmt->num_rows says 0 :(

Comment: __affected_rows:__ — `Returns the total number of rows __changed, deleted, or inserted__ by the last executed statement` (ie from an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement); __num_rows:__ — Return the number of rows in statements __result set__` (ie from a `SELECT` statement)

Comment: If $stmt->num_rows says 0, then no rows were returned by the select query

Comment: does the data in your database match the criteria of your search?

Comment: @MarkBaker but there is a value in database and when I echo $ip then it has value :(

Comment: @RoyJamesSchumacher what do you mean?

Comment: @azamkhan does the value in the database match the ip address being passed into the select statement?

Comment: @RoyJamesSchumacher yes the $ip variable does have value when I echo it.

Comment: @azamkhan but does it match the value in the database?

Comment: I have no clue what are you say @RoyJamesSchumacher . when the select returned the value in the $ip variable that is bound in the bind_result then it means the match was successful and no errors..

Comment: Well the code you've posted here has `$IP=$ClientIP;`.... are you talking about that `$IP` or about `$ip` (remembering that PHP variables are case-sensitive)

Comment: @MarkBaker `$IP` is the one I retrieve from the request and then pass this as param to the query and return `$ip`

Answer (score 1):

`affected_rows` returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.

In order to get the number of rows in the result, you need to get the `mysql_result` object. Try this instead:

```
$stmt->get_result()->num_rows
```

Comment: what is num_rows property or method?

Comment: See my update, you need to get the `mysqli_result` object to read the `num_rows` property

Comment: Try the examples on this doc page: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: I am using parameterized query .. is this causing any issues.

Answer (score 0):

[`affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) does not work on `select` statements, just on DML statements. If you want to know how many rows were retrieved, you should use [`num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

calling `affected_rows` after a select statement will return the same value as `num_rows`

-1 from `affected_rows` means that there was an error try calling `error` on the mysqli object and looking at what the error was (if there is one).

http://docs.php.net/manual/da/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Is the value of $ip the same as value stored under the  ID column in your database?

Comment: James  I pass `$IP` as param to the query and check on its value and return `$ip` which does have a value .. means the query was successful and fetched a value.. :(

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the parameterized query.. the example all show queries without paramters passed into it.. please check the question again..

Comment: Take a look at these examples http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php